# Converting GMT value for DateTimeZone?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I'm currently using this to **convert a timestamp to a user's defined timezone**. My problem is that DateTimeZone() requires a timezone like `Europe/Vienna` or `America/Chicago`:

```
$date = new DateTime("@".$timestamp);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
```

I already looked into supported timezones on https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php but there are so many of them and I don't want users to browse the whole list.

Is there a simple way converting e.g. `GMT+1:00`, `GMT-4:30` or `GMT+5:45` to a correct value for DateTimeZone().

Or is it better to use an array list like I found here: [Convert selected time and timezone to a set timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734678/convert-selected-time-and-timezone-to-a-set-timezone)

Is it better to use UTC or GMT in general for the user to pick?

Thanks!

Comment: GMT-offset based values are ambiguous. A given offset often maps to several timezones.  A given offset may become incorrect for the use when their daylight savings boundary is crossed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably obtain the user's real timezone (selected from the complete list). Using only a static offset from UTC you will not be able to follow the correct daylight savings time rules for the user's location.

PHP's `DateTimeZone` doesn't appear to accept [POSIX timezone strings](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html) so it looks like you're stuck with predefined timezones.

Look in `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc`. There are a bunch of timezones predefined there for UTC plus and minus an integer. The only gotcha is that the sense of + and - is reversed from the normal convention. So just use, for example, "Etc/GMT-9" for a generic timezone with offset +0900.

This doesn't handle all of the possible timezones, like Nepal's weird +0545 but it looks like it's the best option that's easily accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's another way to pass a timezone. I think the time zones used in PHP have to be location-based to determine the DST settings along with the offset.

However, you can still present the options as `GMT+1:00` etc to your users. And you can narrow down the list to only the much-used options (UTC, GMT, PST, etc).